# How to create a gdal.Dataset or xarray.Dataset object from a django.contrib.gis.gdal.GDALRaster object?

Tags: python, django, gdal, python-xarray, geodjango

I am working on a Django project in which I'm trying to get all the raster data from my Database.

Here is my model in models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class RasterWithName(models.Model):
    raster = models.RasterField()
    name = models.TextField()
```

Here is the method I use to get all the rows from my Database in django's shell.

First I have to do a `python manage.py shell` and then run the below code, one by one:

```
all_objects = RasterWithName.objects.all()
first_object_in_database = all_objects[0]
print(first_object_in_database)
```

It prints:

```
RasterWithName object (1)
```

Additionally, running the below line,

```
print(type(first_object_in_database))
```

prints:

```
<class 'geo.models.RasterWithName'>
```

I then run the two lines below:

```
raster = first_object_in_database.raster
print(type(raster))
```

Which prints:

```
<class 'django.contrib.gis.gdal.raster.source.GDALRaster'>
```

How can I convert this `GDALRaster` object into a more known object like a `gdal Dataset`( that can be imported like this: `from osgeo.gdal import Dataset`) or `xarray Dataset` (that can be imported like this: `from xarray import Dataset`)?

#####################################################

**EDIT‌ #1:**

#####################################################

Thanks to [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5997555/val), Here is a working solution:

```
all_objects = RasterWithName.objects.all()
first_object_in_database = all_objects[0]

my_raster = first_object_in_database.raster

gdal_raster = gdal.Open(raster.name)

print(type(gdal_raster))
```

which prints:

```
<class 'osgeo.gdal.Dataset'>
```

However, I don't think this would be very optimal since it simply opens the file from its path on my local storage.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `GDALRaster` object  ... but did you try `gdal.Open(raster.name)`?

Comment: @Val Thank you. It worked.

Comment: @Muser What is your use case? Is there a specific method of GDAL Dataset that you are missing?